# envoy issue with skipping target

Tags: bazel, envoyproxy

envoy: v1.7.0
The following rule

```
load("@envoy//bazel:repositories.bzl", "envoy_dependencies")
envoy_dependencies(repository="@envoy", skip_targets=["io_bazel_rules_go"])
local_repository(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_go",
    path = "/root/io_bazel_rules_go",
)
```

is giving me error :

```
ERROR: xxx/WORKSPACE:47:1: unexpected keyword 'repository' in call to envoy_dependencies(path = "@envoy_deps//", skip_targets = [])
ERROR: Error evaluating WORKSPACE file
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'bazel/repositories.bzl': no such package '@envoy_api//bazel': error loading package 'external': Could not load //external package
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'bazel/repositories.bzl': no such package '@envoy_api//bazel': error loading package 'external': Could not load //external package
INFO: Elapsed time: 6.944s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

Any input on how to skip the build of io_bazel_rules_go will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The first error message is the relevant one, you can ignore the others:

```
ERROR: xxx/WORKSPACE:47:1: unexpected keyword 'repository' in call to envoy_dependencies(path = "@envoy_deps//", skip_targets = [])
```

This tells us that `envoy_dependencies` has no attribute called `repository`, and the signature shows there is `path` instead.

You can check it yourself in the rule's implementation: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/3f59fb5c0f6554f8b3f2e73ab4c1437a63d42668/bazel/repositories.bzl#L182

Comment: yes.. The older envoy had that option but not the current one. Still how one can skip the fork and build of `io_bazel_rules_go ` and tell it to use the repo that I already have in the host.